# Unexpected animation in CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I am working on a static website and have some animations in CSS:

```
*
{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;     
}
```

This is fine and everything and every page is animated in the same way **except one of my HTML documents** which also contains input elements and a textarea:

```
<form action="script/contact-form.php" method="post">
    <b>Full name:</b><br/>
    <input type="text" name="name" /><br/>

    <b>Subject:</b><br>
    <input type="text" name="subject" /><br/>

    <b>E-mail:</b><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <br/><br/>

    <b>Your comments:</b><br/>
    <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
    <br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

For some reason the entire page is then animated (unlike the **other pages**, which are using the **same stylesheet**). I tried disabling this with:

```
form, input, textarea
{
    -moz-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -o-transition: color 0 ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color 0 ease-in-out;
    transition: none;   
}
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Here is what it looks like: http://notrussian.de/stack/contact-us.html. Clicking on other pages without the form has different effects.

This is starting to drive me nuts and I really hope you guys could help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure animating every property of every element is a good idea?

Comment: not sure what the problem is. `*` is already "all elements", so why are you surprised that input elements are covered by that?

Comment: This is too vague to go off of. What do you mean by "for some reason the entire page is animated"? What CSS rules do you have on the form / input / textarea?

Comment: But for some reason it only applies to 1 of my documents, instead of all of them.

Comment: I have no rules specified for input, textarea besides some padding

Comment: You probably have a different statement canceling the `* {...` code block on the pages where there are no animations, or that CSS is not actually loaded on those pages. That block says to animate  *every property* on *every element* – so you're bound to have unexpected animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What is going wrong

You say :

> For some reason the entire page is then animated

That's the expected behaviour when you use this code :

```
* {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;     
}
```

The CSS selector `*` means that any CSS properties for that selector are applied to every element on your web page.

The value `all` for property `transition` means that every property of those elements that can be animated will be animated.

So, the combination of CSS selector `*` and CSS property `transition: all` means that every property that can be animated will be animated for every HTML element on your web page.

### Solution 1 : Animate ONLY what you want to animate

You could do something like this :

```
/** Get rid of this code
* * {
*    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
*    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
*    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
*    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
*    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;     
* }
*/

.animate, .animate * {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;     
}
```

Then, in your HTML, add `class=animate` to every element you want to animate :

```
<ul class="animate">
  ...
</ul>
```

There are many alternative implementations, but this is one of the easiest ones. For the best approach, see "Additional improvements" herebelow.

### Solution 2 : Disable animation for what you DON'T want to animate

This should work :

```
form, input, textarea {
    -moz-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -o-transition: color 0 ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color 0 ease-in-out;
    transition: none;   
}
```

You say you tried it, but I can't find it anywhere in your code when I go to the page you referenced. Anyway, make sure you put it BEHIND the `*` selector.

### Additional improvements

For the sake of performance AND to prevent unexpected behavior, it's best to always set animation ONLY for those properties and those elements you really want to animate.

So, if you want to animate both the width and height of your `div` elements, you should do something like this :

```
div {
    -moz-transition: width 2s, height 4s;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 4s;
    -o-transition: width 2s, height 4s;
    -ms-transition: width 2s, height 4s;
    transition: width 2s, height 4s;
}
```

If you want to animate just the background of your `#navigation li` elements, you should do something like this :

```
#navigation li {
    -moz-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: You are right, I am just confused why this only seems to apply to 1 of my 5 HTML documents which all link to the same stylesheet?

Comment: @grandel I'm not sure what you're talking about. When I go to http://notrussian.de/stack/, I get the same behavior for each of the five pages.